# Что за шифровка?

Tags: php, криптография

Есть следующий зашифрованный текстовый файл и пароль к нему, как его разшифровать и что это за метод шифрования?

```
def5 0200 73e8 88f7 464f fdc5 3999 ca23
1bbb 15c3 bd6e 014b c957 7b47 178e b0a5
e22a 1ae3 f864 fb64 b42f f14b a6a9 5ee2
2a80 5251 bf78 157c 6cb3 dc2e 719c 4e94
eae9 6445 b3b0 d309 a3e4 850e 9e54 7f87
e6ce c7b3 67e3 bc94 58bf 7b23 ce3a 6cb5
05f1 e25a 58c5 aa6a 0b82 4272 b71b 9e14
5745 e8b5 d5a6 29b3 c8bb d152 1245 7a77
7ed6 ad42 3118 0485 cd
```

Знаю что этот шифр конвертируется в с  HEX в Binary,  и строчный пароль тоже конвертируется

Comment: Где в вопросе ваши попытки в решении данного вопроса?

Comment: @ArtikSlayer добавил

Comment: Тут не может быть никакого ответа. Это может быть абсолютно любой блочный/поточный шифр, потому что они на выходе генерируют байты, которые неотличимые от случайного набора байт. Вы видите в этих байтах какую-то закономерность?

Comment: по двоичным данным вы никак не определите какой алгоритм использован. можно только заметить что это скорее всего не какой то блочный алгоритм, так как вряд ли длина блока даст нечетное количество байт. Если конечно файл ничем не дополнили после шифрования. на простой подстановочный то же не похоже, разброс значений не был бы столь хаотичным. Начать можно с того что посмотреть изменяется ли длина файла при шифровании

Comment: ТУЖе юбюю гцУх ххЖг дфдЖ ЖТСе циии СЯбц
аРРР аеСц РТфУ юадР Сиег гРдг агхУ РюЯе
УббЯ аЯУц Жхфд ЖРфд РдбЖ ЖадР ЯфЯи еУУб
бЯхю ебеа РЖгх аегС фСРц ТСбУ гаиС дУид
УЯУи фдде РцРю Тцюи ЯцУд хеюУ иУед гЖхг
УфСУ СгРц фгУц РСид ехРЖ гРбц СУцЯ фСРе
юеЖа УбеЯ ехСе ЯЯфЯ юРхб дбгб РгаР иУад
егде УхРе ТеЯф биРц СхРР Таеб абде гЯгг
гУТф ЯТдб цаах юдхе СТ

Comment: Зашифрованная информация и просто информация это одно и то-же. Вы сначала узнайте, нужно ли вам что-то догадаться. Может быть это просто екзешник. Есть ещё такое понятие как закрытый ключ. Если сообщение = 0 - это значит "Привет!", а 1 - "До свидания".

Answer (score 1):

Обычно надежность алгоритма шифрования определяется сокрытием ключа, а не самого алгоритма)

С одним и тем же ключом на выходе получится разный расшифрованный текст. Причем есть даже ненулевая вероятность, что при расшифровке может быть получен [ложный результат, выглядящий как верный](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Honey_encryption). На вашем месте я бы попробовал грубой силой применять популярные алгоритмы шифрования и смотреть, во что дешифровался шифртекст. Мне видится это единственным, хоть и сложным, способом.

Comment: Файл конвертируется с HEX to Binary